# Unable to enter text in dropdown

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I tried the following code to enter the value BLR in a auto suggestive dropdown however although its clicking it, its now entering the text.

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class testcase2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "//Users//suva//Downloads//chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
        WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.id("fromCity"));
        source.click();
        System.out.println(source.isEnabled());
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        source.sendKeys("BLR");
        //source.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you click on the default 'from' selection, there is an dropdown with another input to type.

Try like this:

```
driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");

WebElement triggerFromDropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("fromCity"));
triggerFromDropdown.click();

WebElement fromInput = driver.findElement(By.css(".autoSuggestPlugin input[placeholder='From']"));
fromInput.sendkeys('Dubai');
```

Answer (score -1):

There can be many reasons why it is not working. It would ave been beneficial if you could provide the DOM element as well..

However a solution would be to enter text through JavaScript Executor.
The code will be something like :-

```
WebElement webelement = driver.FindElement(By.id("fromCity"));
                JavaScriptExecutor executor = (JavaScriptExecutor)driver;
                executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value='" + "BLR" + "';", webelement);
```

For better authenticity of the above code, I need DOM. It should work though.

Comment: you can see the website in driver.get and there is an another input which being triggered after you click.

Comment: I will check it. I missed that line.. Thanks!